# pdf upload functionality in telerik rich text editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik-mvc, rich-text-editor

I am using ASP.NET MVC Telerik editor in my project , the telerik editor doesn't support PDF upload functionality, well it supports image upload, is there a way I can include PDF upload functionality or have anyone tried to do something like that?

My settings:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Editor().Name(clientId)
/*.Encode(false) weird. Settings "Encode(false)" doesn't work on category & product details page
Now we have to manually decode values*/
.Value(Model)
.Tools(tools => tools
.Custom(settings => settings.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "t-html", onclick = "viewRichHtmlEditorSource" + random + "(event)", title="Edit HTML" })))
.FileBrowser(browser => browser.Browse("Browse", "ImageBrowser")
    .Thumbnail("Thumbnail", "ImageBrowser")
    .Upload("Upload", "ImageBrowser")
    .DeleteFile("DeleteFile", "ImageBrowser")
    .DeleteDirectory("DeleteDirectory", "ImageBrowser")
    .CreateDirectory("CreateDirectory", "ImageBrowser")))
```

How to add your suggested functionality within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does support pdf, i'm using it for pdf and it works just fine. 
What you have to look out for is the SIZE of the file, you have to check and make sure it's not over 5MB big

Here is a sample of what I'm using:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewFileName)
    @(Html.Telerik().Upload()
       .Name("attachment")
       .Multiple(false)
       .ClientEvents(events => events.OnSelect("onSelect"))
    )
</div>
```

The onSelect script:

```
function onSelect(e) {
    if (e.files[0].size > 5000000) {
        alert('The file size is too large for upload');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    // Array with information about the uploaded files
    var files = e.files;
    var ext = $('#attachment').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if ($.inArray(ext, ['pdf']) == -1) {
        alert('This type of file is restricted from being uploaded due to security reasons');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $("#NewFileName").val(files[0].name);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The Controller action must receive the attachement in the signature like so:

```
public ActionResult EditFile(HttpPostedFileBase attachment) {
...
}
```

Comment: You will need to use the Telerik Upload control in combination with the editor. The uploader is specific to uploading files.. the editor control is for editing and embedded Html. The Image portion allows you to link to a known file location or upload an image (using the upload control behind the scenes)